# add tooltip with count to layer_bars

Tags: ggvis

Suppose I have the following graph

```
library(ggvis)
mtcars%>% ggvis(~factor(cyl)) %>% layer_bars()
```

How can I add a tooltip with the count variable?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the trick:

```
library(ggvis)
mtcars  %>% ggvis(~factor(cyl)) %>% layer_bars() %>%
  add_tooltip(function(df) (df$stack_upr_ - df$stack_lwr_))
```

Comment: `function(df) (df$stack_upr_)` is enough, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34003037/3409615)