# How to add tooltip with shares to ggvis histogram?

Tags: r, ggvis

I would like to create an interactive histogram which gives information about the bins by hover. [This thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggvis/qZ3z8EC4DMs) gives answer to how to add tooltip with count numbers.

```
library("ggvis")

cocaine %>%  
    ggvis(x = ~weight) %>%
    layer_histograms() %>%
    add_tooltip(function(df) (paste("count:", df$stack_upr_ - df$stack_lwr_)))
```

How can I add the share of each bin as well? I should somehow add `nrow(cocaine)` to ggvis and create the shares from count but I did not succeed on how to achieve that (tried to take the suggestions of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24519980/add-data-to-ggvis-tooltip-thats-contained-in-the-input-dataset-but-not-directly) but apparently that solves a different problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this I imagine:

```
cocaine %>%  
  ggvis(x = ~weight) %>%
  layer_histograms() %>%
  add_tooltip(function(df) paste("count:", df$stack_upr_, 'share:', 
                           format(df$stack_upr_/nrow(cocaine), digits=2)))
```

This will show both the share and the bin number.

[image]

Also, as a side note you do not need `df$stack_upr_ - df$stack_lwr_` because `df$stack_lwr_` will be zero. Just `df$stack_upr_` will do.